# Vertices in directed graph such that there exists a path to every another vertex from this one

Tags: algorithm, graph

How can I find all vertices in a directed graph such that every another vertex is reachable from this one? Now I can "invent" only O(|V|^3) algo -- a DFS/BFS from every vertex, but I'm sure, there exists a faster way to solve this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run a [strongly connected components algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component#Algorithms) to collapse the graph into a [directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) of its strongly connected components. There must be at least one strongly connected component with no incoming edges. If there is exactly one, the nodes in that component are the ones you're looking for. If there are multiple strongly connected components with no incoming edges, there is no node from which all other nodes are reachable.

Comment: Oh man, you're genius, it's a solution I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: See comments below!

Sometimes it's all about the terminology. Here the magic word is reachability (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability)). Unfortunately, I don't think you'll like the results.

- If not all the answers are needed, running BFS/DFS is actually recommended.
- Otherwise, use the Floyd-Warshall algorithm. Still runs in O(|V|<sup>3</sup>).
- Certain optimized algorithms exist for special cases - see Wikipedia for more detail.

So that's probably not what you wanted to hear.

Comment: I may be wrong (not following the definition 100%), but isn't this solving a more difficult problem (i.e. getting the reachability between all vertices, rather than just those able to reach all other vertices)? Using [strongly connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component#Algorithms), as suggested in the other answer, seems like it would work in less than O(|V|^3).

Comment: Yep, I think you're right, so I'll upvote the other answer. I learned something new today! Do you think @user2357112 's way of doing this is published anywhere? He doesn't refer to it as such and it seems like a quite clever way of solving a problem others might want to solve, too.